# sql select running total

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help wit this query

I would like to group by date1, and then order by date  ascending and update the RunningTotal field with the cumulative result

So far this is what I have

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.RunningTotal (
    date1 date    
    ,Entry int
    ,RunningTotal int
)

INSERT INTO dbo.RunningTotal (date1,Entry,RunningTotal)VALUES('2015-01-03',100,NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.RunningTotal (date1,Entry,RunningTotal)VALUES('2015-02-03',200,NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.RunningTotal (date1,Entry,RunningTotal)VALUES('2015-05-03',300,NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.RunningTotal (date1,Entry,RunningTotal)VALUES('2015-07-13',400,NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.RunningTotal (date1,Entry,RunningTotal)VALUES('2015-01-03',-500,NULL)

UPDATE dbo.RunningTotal
SET RunningTotal = RT2.RunningTotal
FROM dbo.RunningTotal RT1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        Entry
        ,(SELECT SUM(Entry) FROM dbo.RunningTotal WHERE Entry <= rt.Entry) As RunningTotal
    FROM dbo.RunningTotal rt
) RT2
ON RT1.Entry = RT2.Entry

SELECT * FROM dbo.RunningTotal
```

But in this select I´m not taking into account the date and the grouping

Thanks!!!

Comment: Could you specify which SELECT exactly you want to group by date etc..

Comment: What version of SQL-Server?

Comment: Please post the expected output.

Comment: Which sql-server version are you using ?  In 2012 there are window functions (Lead-Lag) just for this purpose.  In previous versions its a bit different.

Comment: @Amir: you don't need lead() or lag() for this, a simple `sum(entry) (over order by date1)` will do the job (but yes, that requires SQL Server 2012)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - True, sum over is a simpler solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues with your query.  The correlation clause needs to keep track of the date, and the table name needs to be an alias in the `FROM` clause.

```
UPDATE toupdate
    SET RunningTotal = RT.RunningTotal
FROM dbo.RunningTotal toupdate INNER JOIN
     (SELECT rt.*
             (SELECT SUM(rt2.Entry)
              FROM dbo.RunningTotal rt2
              WHERE rt2.date1 <= toupdate.date1
             ) As RunningTotal
      FROM dbo.RunningTotal rt
     ) RT
     ON toupdate.date1 = rt.date1;
```

You don't specify what to do when the dates are the same.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I just did what @Amir sugested: 
select entry, date1, sum(entry) OVER (order by date1) as Total 
from #RunningTotal 
order by date1 asc

Answer (score 0):

As you probably want to update the running total after a new record is inserted, it would make sense to do this with a trigger.  Below is some simple SQL to create a trigger to do this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateRunningTotal   ON  dbo.RunningTotal
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @date DATE, @total INT
--get the date of the insert record
SET @date = (SELECT date1 from inserted)
--get the total for that date
SET @total = (SELECT SUM(Entry) FROM dbo.RunningTotal WHERE dbo.RunningTotal.date1 = @date)
--update all records with new running total
UPDATE dbo.RunningTotal SET dbo.RunningTotal.RunningTotal = @total WHERE  dbo.RunningTotal.date1 = @date

END
GO
```